# IBM Rational System Architect using DB2

Tags: sql-server, db2

Currently I am looking to setting up IBM Rational System Architect 11.4.3.0, however I need to get a database setup first to connect with it. I see from the system requirements it only supports SQL Server/Oracle. Due to various restrictions, I am unable to use this currently and the only available option is DB2. Is it possible to hook System Architect to DB2, and if so, how?

I already know that there is a way to do this, however cannot seem to find out, as another team in a separate department has done exactly this. However I was wondering if anyone here had any better solutions, examples, or anything that would assist with this task. Perhaps a way to make the DB2 server look like an SQL server to System Architect, or a roundabout way of connecting the two.

Comment: Why not install the free SQL Server Express edition?

Comment: Heavily secure system, unable to install any software not verified/registered. It would honestly be preferred to just install it but is sadly not an option at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 is also product of IBM.  The generic install should contain the necessary JARs to connect to DB2:

```
Directory of C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\deploytool\itp\plugins\
com.ibm.datatools.db2_1.0.3.v200805071403\driver

2012-11-02  20:31         1,973,658 db2jcc.jar
2012-11-02  20:31             2,068 db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar
2012-11-02  20:31             1,015 db2jcc_license_cu.jar
               3 File(s)      1,976,741 bytes
```

Comment: I think it might be more of an issue that SA doesn't actually have a method to connect to anything other then SQL-Server, and that's all that is supported according to the IBM website. Can I get around those issues using these jar files?

Comment: We no longer use RSA, but it should be easy to set up a JDBC url:

`jdbc:db2://db2host:db2port/database`

setting the classpath to the JARs listed above, the class to load is 

`com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver`

Answer (score 0):

I know that this may be a little late, but just wanted to correctly provide a response for System Architect's (SA) support for DB2.

If you are looking at using DB2 for storing the SA encyclopedias, then this is not supported. SA only supports SQL Server and Oracle as it's back-end repository to store the various artifacts (diagram, definitions, etc) i.e. an encyclopedia.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed, your answer is correct. Although its possible with some coding magic and shenanigans/etc.