# Does Unicom System Architect still support using Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, rational-rsa

When System Architect was an IBM product it supported Oracle DB.

The current version is 11.4.4.2.

Reading the [vendor's product page](https://teamblue.unicomsi.com/products/system-architect/) does not list Oracle, it only lists MS SQL Server. But a 2016 [Unicom report](http://www.systemarchitect.info/Scalability_of_UNICOM_System_Architect_11_4.pdf) says 11.4 supports Oracle.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Architect) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33835017/58794) say it supports Oracle, but they are both old information.

Does anyone have experience on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on vendor conversations, 11.4.2.7 does support Oracle. 11.4.3 *likely* does not.

Answer (score 0):

On the page you refer to press the evaluate-button and you will see

> **Request for Information**
>   If you would like to submit a Request for Information for an Enterprise Architecture tool, please send an email to Architect.Sales@unicomsi.com

So why not ask the vendor? I think he will know.

Comment: I did that first, no answer as of yet.